# How did Rose Noble know about this alien?

Tags: doctor-who

In "The Star Beast",the 2023 Special of Doctor Who, we are introduced to Rose Noble, the daughter of former companion Donna Noble. We are shown that because of Donna's involvement in the Meta-Crisis, Rose was born with a portion of Donna's Time Lord energy, which influenced her life in many ways. One of Rose's hobbies was to make dolls based on aliens that Donna and the Doctor encountered. Among these dolls, we can identify a Dalek, a Cyberman, and this dog-like creature.

[image: The doglike doll Rose made in The Star Beast]

They do not name it but the only alien we have met in Doctor who that would match its description would be Karvanista. The last of the the doglike protectors of humans called the Lupari.

[image: The Karvanista from the Flux]

This is a bit odd since, as far as I know, the Doctor never encountered the Lupari until 'The Halloween Apocalypse', a long time after Donna left. Because of this, Donna would not have any shared memories about them, and neither would Rose.

Is there any extended universe material that has Donna encountering the Lupari or any other dog-like alien before she left the Doctor, or is there some other explanation for how she might have known this

Comment: I’m guessing the time lord energy from the meta crisis is timey wimey since, once Donna is “reactivated” she somehow knows that this is the 14th not the 10th Dr, asking “why did this face come back?”

Comment: Second pic looks like an Ewok :-)

Comment: @RedCaio That is possible. But Rose made her toys long before the Doctor came back or Donna got 'reactivated'

Comment: Well, you say as far as we know, but why should we assume that the Tenth Doctor and Donna Noble never saw a Lupar? Since the Lupari have a rather close relationship with humans (albeit not one that most *humans* are aware of), and the Doctor spends an inordinate amount of time around humans, I would think they would be very familiar with the Lupari and have met them many times—including, possibly, with Donna.

Comment: @Adamant That is a reasonable guess, but unless we have some stories talking about it it is still unknown. If we look at the other dolls she made, Cybermen, Oods, Daleks, Judoon, they are all species that has had a large impact on the Doctor. For the Lupari at the time of the Meta-Crisis there is none as far as we know.

Comment: The Doctor was clearly unaware of that relationship at the time of Flux, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other clues, I'd guess that Rose's memories are not the result of a single information dump, but that the metacrisis somehow created an ongoing bond. That is because in addition to Karvanista, there are other references to things that postdate the Tenth Doctor's run. The workings of the metacrisis are only very hazily defined but as "weird Time Lord stuff" there is a lot of scope for weirdness in how it might manifest.

### Atraxi

I think that this toy (held by the Meep at about 19 minutes in) is meant to be an Atraxi.

[image: A toy consisting of a large central eye, surrounded by a ring of blue fluff, with little white fluffy protruberances on the outside]

They appeared in *The Eleventh Hour* (here at about 47 minutes in).

[image: A big floaty creature that is a central eyeball surrounded by radiating irregular spikes, like blue icicles]

That episode is the debut for the Eleventh Doctor and is also the first appearance of this species. They don't seem to have encountered each other before (the Atraxi don't know who he is; he doesn't call them "Atraxi" until after Prisoner Zero drops the name, and gives no sign of recognition).

### Cyberman

In the scene where the connection is explained, and we see the various toys, the Cyberman one is accompanied by a voiceover saying "Upgrade in progress". This is from the Eleventh Doctor episode *Nightmare in Silver*, although it's also a fairly generic new-Who Cyberman thing to say (close to their dialogue in *Rise of the Cybermen* / *Age of Steel*).

### Lupari

The BBC put out a behind-the-scenes video (["A Tour of Rose's Shed"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBx2mFAJbYY)) which pairs the toy from the question with an image of Karvanista (at 1:10). So this is certainly meant to be him. (The same video identifies the image above which I thought was an Atraxi as a Dalek, but I think that's a mistake given that the episode makes a different blue toy be the Dalek.)

In the series, the Thirteenth Doctor is supposed to have known Karvanista long ago but had the memories removed. By the time she encounters him in *Flux*, she's not aware of the connection between the human and Lupari species, which would suggest that there aren't any off-screen encounters between the Doctor and the Lupari in the interim.

### Karvanista-Eleven-Davros

The following sketch from the "Rose's Shed" video did not make it to the episode, but is indicative of some loss of fidelity in the memories or sense-impressions. This shows something about how the production team thought about what is going on with Rose's images.

[image: Sketch of a doglike creature wearing a fez, with a blue third eye in the middle of his forehead, and seated in a bright yellow version of Davros's chair]

Here we see a sort of hybrid of Karvanista, the Eleventh Doctor, and Davros. This hasn't happened in the series - yet. But it is consistent with Rose getting a rough idea of stuff that's been happening to the Doctor. At least two of the elements (Karvanista, the fez) are things that the Tenth Doctor ought not to know about. The fez appeared for him in *The Day of the Doctor* but that likely took place after *Journey's End* and he is not meant to remember it afterwards in any case.

### Conclusion

The Lupari appearance could be interpreted as any of -

1. A long-buried memory from a pre-Hartnell Doctor. But these memories are supposed to have been erased.
2. An offscreen encounter sometime before the events of *Journey's End* when the metacrisis took place. But if that happened, the Doctor seems to have forgotten all about it by the time she met them again.
3. Their reappearance during the Flux event. But this is after the metacrisis was formed.

Given the other clues, especially the Atraxi, I think that (3) is actually the most likely. For this to work diegetically, we'd have to imagine that the metacrisis entails an ongoing connection between the Doctor, Donna and Rose - tenuous enough to give Rose an impression of these creatures but something short of her having detailed knowledge of the Doctor's adventures.

Comment: The ongoing connection theory is also supported by the fact that once the metacrisis energy is restored, Donna knows, without being told, that the Doctor she is meeting now is a later incarnation than the one she previously travelled with, and that his previous incarnation was a woman.